# How can I find the address of the current line in a file?

Tags: java, file

If we assume we have file 1 which has the following context.

### File 1

I read a book.

### Mary likes red color.

Now I want to append a sentence to the file 1. My question is how I can find the exact address that the given sentence will be written in the file1. I need to save this address to access the line directly instead of reading all lines of file 1 to find this specific sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A position of something (e.g. the start of a line) in file is not an "address".  It is an offset (in bytes) from the start of a file.

So if you are about to append a line to a file, the byte offset of the start of that line will be the byte offset of the end of the file *before* you do the append.  And that is the same as the length of the file (in bytes).  You can get that by calling `File.length()` (modulo the problem of race conditions ...).

Now if you are appending lots of lines, repeatedly asking how long the file is inefficient.  And then there is the fact that if your output to the file is buffered, the file size will only get updated when the buffer contents are flushed.  So you would need to flush as well, which is even more inefficient.

If you are trying to find line positions repeatedly, it is probably better to track the file size / position yourself by *counting* the bytes that are written.  How best to do that depends on what data you are writing, and how you are writing it to the file.